# Kernel emulation with Qemu

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, busybox

I'm actually trying to emulate the linux kernel using Qemu and busybox.
So far I made this kernel image:
http://depositfiles.com/files/l9x9veg09
And launched Qemu using these arguments:
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 256 -s -hda rootfs.img -kernel linux-2.6.34.12/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda \ init=/bin/sh"
But once the kernel is launched I get a message saying:
Kernel Panic. No init found. Try passing init= option to kernel...
I though adding "init=/bin/sh" to the arguments would solve the problem but it didn't. I'm a begginer in this domain. Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Busybox, you want to pass -initrd initramfs instead of init=/bin/sh to qemu. Try this

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 256 -s -hda rootfs.img -kernel linux-2.6.34.12/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd initramfs -append "root=/dev/sda"
```

Comment: The initramfs is an initial ram disk that is loaded into memory upon startup. You can see how to create it with busybox [here](http://mgalgs.github.com/2012/03/23/how-to-build-a-custom-linux-kernel-for-qemu.html). If you have [mkinitramfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/mkinitramfs.8.html) available, you may use that instead for creating the initramfs file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work by using a pre-build version of busybox which was statically linked (found on the website). The old one was dynamically linked and compiling it as a static executable was a real pain (it seems that glibc does not support static linking anymore).